# Segmantation Fault in C

Tags: c, list, segmentation-fault, alphabetical

This program will create link list from text alphabetically.
It is case-sensitive and it will eliminate the marks.

When I run the program, it gives a segmentation fault. I can't find where the problem is. I added the `printf()` in order to find the mistake but i can't.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct NODE {
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct NODE *next;
}NODE;

char *get_word(FILE *fp){
     printf("getWord");
     char *str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);

     char c;
     do {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if (c == EOF) 
            return 0;
        } while (!isalpha(c));
        do {
             printf("getWord");

        *str++ = tolower(c);
        c = fgetc(fp);
        printf("Word");

        } while (isalpha(c));

        return str;
        }

void insert(NODE* sortedList, char *word) { 
   printf("INSERT ");

   char *str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
   if (sortedList == NULL || word < sortedList->word) {

      NODE *ekle;
      ekle=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
      strcpy(ekle->word,word);
      ekle->count = 1;
      ekle->next = sortedList;
      sortedList = ekle;
   }
   else {
        // 
      NODE *current = sortedList->next;
      NODE *pre = sortedList;
      while (current != NULL && word > current->word) { 
         pre = current;
         current = current->next;
      }
      if (current != NULL && word == current->word) {

         (current->count)++;
      }
      else {

         NODE *ekle;
         ekle=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
         strcpy(ekle->word,word);
         ekle->count = 1;
         ekle->next = current;
         pre->next = ekle;
      }
   }
}

void createList(FILE* fp,NODE *n) {
   printf("CREATELIST ");
   char *word;
   strcpy(word,get_word(fp));
   puts(word);
   while (strcmp(word,"")) {
      printf("Create_LİST2");
      insert(n,word);
      word = get_word(fp);
   }
}

NODE *head;


int main(){
    NODE *list=NULL;;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen( "text.txt", "r" );
    head=list;

    while(!feof(fp)){

                     createList(fp,list);

                     }
    while(list->next != NULL){
                     printf("%s", list->word);
                     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tried to use a debugger?

Comment: always check the result of fopen(). ALWAYS

Comment: you have no boundarycheck in your get_word() while(getc())

Comment: Where does the segmentation fault happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A major problem is this line

```
*str++ = tolower(c);
```

This changes the pointer `str`, so when you return `str` from the function it actually points *beyond* the string. A string which you, by the way, do not terminate.

Another major problem are these lines:

```
NODE *ekle;
ekle=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
strcpy(ekle->word,word);
```

Here you allocate a `NODE` structure, but you do not allocate memory for `ekle->word`, so it points to indeterminate memory. You have the above code in two places.

Equal to the above allocation problem, you have

```
char *word;
strcpy(word,get_word(fp));
```

Here too you don't allocate memory for `word`, so you have a pointer to indeterminate memory.

---

Also, in C [you should not cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). You should also look out for warnings from the compiler, and if you don't get any from the code you have then you need to enable more warnings. Compiler warnings are often a sign of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which is what all of the above leads to. And finally, next to the compiler I would argue that a debugger is a developers best tool. Learn to use it, it would have helped you with some of the above problems.

Comment: how can i terminate this part?

Comment: @user3546593 All strings in C must be terminated by the character `'\0'`. For the allocation problems look at the [`strdup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) function.

Comment: @user3546593 Also be careful, what if the string you read from the file is longer than 99 (100 with terminator) characters?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one problem:

```
char c;
do {
    c = fgetc(fp);
    if (c == EOF) 
        return 0;
```

This is wrong; `fgetc()` returns `int`, since `EOF` does not fit in a `char`. The first line should therefore be:

```
int c;
```

Comment: will just return fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

not the segfault, but: you malloc str, without using or freeing it

```
void insert(NODE* sortedList, char *word) { 
  printf("INSERT ");
  char *str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
```

Comment: i fixed there.it should be *word

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Hint: "*word" is a _char_ and you're assigning a pointer to it. Reverted your edit

Answer (score 0):

Fist you have to verify if the file is correctly open. Then AFAIK the strcpy requires that destination has enough space to store the data (line 74), instead of "char *word" use "char word[255]" for instance (if you know the size limit).

Answer (score 0):

**Your main problem is here:**

```
*str++ = tolower(c);
```

First of all, once you increment `str`, you no longer hold a pointer to the dynamically allocated memory. Therefore, you will not be able to release that memory at a later point in the execution of your program, which will eventually lead to memory leaks. Second, when you return `str` at the end of the function, you are **not** returning a pointer to that string as you're probably hoping to.

**Additional problems are:**

1. You are not making sure that no more than 99 characters are stored.
2. You are not terminating the string pointed by `str` with a null-character.
3. You are not de-allocating the string pointed by `str` if an `EOF` is encountered.
4. You are not using an `int` in order to store the return value of function `fgetc`.

**Here is how your function should look like:**

```
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 101

char* get_word(FILE* fp)
{
    char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_WORD_LEN);
    int c,i;
    do
    {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if (c == EOF)
        {
            free(str);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    while (!isalpha((char)c));
    i = 0;
    do
    {
        str[i++] = tolower((char)c);
        c = fgetc(fp);
    }
    while (isalpha((char)c) && i < MAX_WORD_LEN-1);
    str[i] = 0;
    return str;
}
```

Please note that if a word in your file is longer than `MAX_WORD_LEN-1` characters, then you will essentially "lose" the last character that was read, because it will not be stored anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here i write code which may helps you to understand problem. It's not exact what as your program does but somewhat similar and easier to understand and also find your all problems solution from below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct NODE
{
   char word[100];
   int count;
   struct NODE *next;
}NODE;

NODE *head = NULL;
NODE *list = NULL;

void insert(char *word)
{
   if (list == NULL)
   {
      list = calloc(1, sizeof(NODE));
      if (NULL == list)
      {
         perror("Memory allocation failed");
         return;
      }
      strncpy(list->word, word, 99);
      list->count = 1;
      list->next = NULL;
      head = list;
   }
   else
   {
      list->next = calloc(1, sizeof(NODE));
      if (NULL == list->next)
      {
         perror("Memory allocation failed");
         return;
      }
      strncpy(list->next->word, word, 99);
      list->next->count = 1;
      list->next->next = NULL;
      list = list->next;
   }
}

void createList(FILE* fp)
{
   char word[100] = {0};
   while (EOF != fscanf(fp, "%99s", word))
   {
      if (0 < strlen(word))
      {
         insert(word);
      }
      memset(word, 0x00, 100);
   }
}

int main()
{
   FILE *fp = NULL;
   fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
   if (NULL == fp)
   {
      //File is not readable
      perror("text.txt file open failed");
      return -1;
   }

   createList(fp);

   list = head;
   while(NULL != list)
   {
      printf("%s\n", list->word);
      list = list->next;
   }

   if (NULL != fp)
   {
      fclose(fp);fp = NULL;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**And also create function to free all memory which is allocated in insert function.**

Comment: can you see that problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241760/add-node-alphabetical-in-c

Comment: also i try to insert the nodes alphabetically.here is the main problem